# Vuex only updating component when clicking on the button of the first row inside for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, getter

I am messing around with Vuex and I almost got it working, there's only this issue which is bothering me. You see, I have a product list, each product has its own "addToCart()" on-click event.

After a product has been added to the cart, it should update the cart in the Home.vue component. Weirdly enough this only updates when clicking on the addToCart button of the first product or when you make use of the button for the first time for the second product. Only if you click on the button of the first product it will update the quantity for both products.

This is my code, here is the component Home.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div v-for="product in cart" :key="product.id">
      {{product.name}} {{product.quantity}}
    </div>
    <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
        {{product.name}}
        <button @click="addToCart(product)">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  /* eslint-disable */
  name: 'Home',
  data () {
    return {
      products: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Appeltaart',
          price: '20.00'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Chocoladetaart',
          price: '15.40'
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    cart() {
      return this.$store.getters.cart
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
  },
  methods: {
    addToCart(product) {
      this.$store.commit('addToCart', product)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

At last, here is my Vuex file called Index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  /* eslint-disable */
  state: {
    cart: [],
    newCartItem: {
      id: 0,
      name: '',
      price: 0,
      quantity: 0,
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    addToCart (state, product) {
      console.log(state.cart)
      let findProduct = state.cart.find(o => o.id === product.id)
      if ( findProduct ) {
          findProduct.quantity += 1;
      } else {
          state.newCartItem.id = product.id
          state.newCartItem.name = product.name;
          state.newCartItem.price = product.price;
          state.newCartItem.quantity = 1;
          state.cart.push(state.newCartItem)
          state.newCartItem = {}
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  },
  getters: {
    cart: state => state.cart
  }
})
```

There is also this error when clicking on the addToCart of the first product:

```
[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '1'. This may cause an update error.
[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '2'. This may cause an update error.
```

**EDIT** Not only the first product, it's always the addToCart of the second product you click

**UPDATE** Fixed the duplicate keys issue

Comment: Seems to be that your key is not unique. Try replacing your <div> with the for loop wit this: <div v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index">

This just makes it so you don't use your product.id but your index (like in a for loop) as your key. That should in almost all cases remove the duplicate keys issue.

Comment: That still gives me the same errors unfortunately

Comment: I'm guessing then that it is because you have 2 v-for's and they both might be using the same keys. Although I'm not sure.

You could try the 'index' strategy I said but then in both your v-for's and in the first on your could make your key for example :key="'cart-product-' + index" and in your second v-for :key="'product-' + index" that should in theory eliminate the possibility of any duplicate keys

Comment: Thanks! It eliminates the errors completely, but still it only updates the quantity of the cartitems when clicking on the addtocart of the first product.

Comment: "findProduct.quantity += 1;" I'm not sure if that line will actually updates the state...

You might have to replace find() with findIndex() and then replace "findProduct.quantity += 1;" with state.cart[findProductIndex].quantity += 1;

I don't think it will update the state otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `state.cart.push(state.newCartItem)` by `state.cart.push(Object.assign({},state.newCartItem))` in your store

It will put an observer in the state that might do the trick

Your cart will be

```
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
```

instead of

```
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {id: 2, name: "Chocoladetaart", price: "15.40", quantity: 2, __ob__: Observer}
```

Comment: And that the the trick! Thank you so much :)